# Should I use a relational database for storing my XML documents

Tags: sql, xml, database

I work with and write technical documentation which is written in XML using various schemas. I have developed a fairly simple Windows Forms application which we now use in office as a workflow system. The program can check in, check out and move around a validation process. The program uses a common 'data.xml' file to read and write from which keeps track of notes, author, status, and various other things.

However, at the moment the application is pointing to a folder structure on a shared drive which contains all the xml files that are in each project, and also the data.xml file which holds the project data for the program. So when somebody checks out a file, the app simply moves the file from one folder to another (invisible to the user), updates the data.xml file them updates the listViews in the UI.

This works fine, unless of course several people are working the same project, and the client applications try to write to the data.xml file at the same time.

So i thought what i'd like to do, is to migrate the whole system over to a database. So instead of storing the XML files in folders, it stores them in a database like SQL. Now i have absolutely no experience of databases, and therefore was hoping for a pointer to kick me off in the right direction. Ideally I need to be able to query the xml documents in the database, so i want to be able to use Xquery, and ideally run processes on all the files at ones. For example at the moment i can run XSLT on entire projects 'cus they're just sat in a folder.

So my question is, what type of DB should i be looking at in order to retain this kind of functionality? Relational like SQL, or perhaps an xml database?

Note: The xml files are a maximum of a few hundred Kbs each.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing xml documents in the database, I would say to use database for project and customer specific data. If most of your xml files don't defer too much, you can use xml templates and coming back to your point of using XSLT to update these templates with useful data before presenting. Where do my xml templates go? It can be on your file system or in a database. This avoids storing massive xml documents and avoids duplication of xml code in the database.

Comment: Thank for the comment. The xml, or at least the content within the xml tags, is very different from document to document. I do eventually want to get it all into a database either way so i'd like to know which way would be advised. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all the monkey business, can you find a source control system that allows only one person to check out a file at a time. Or just use some sort of file locking mechanism to limit access to only one person at a time.

Answer (score -1):

"... what type of DB should I be looking at in order order to retain this kind of functionality?"

There's really only one database type - RDBMs. All flavors of relational datbase support XML, text or binary storage for things like files and documents.

To me, the bigger questions is whether with normal programming and a SQL database you'll be able to support document storage in a multi-user environment. The short answer is, I don't think so, at least not without an enormous amount of work on your part.

The problem is this: let's say you and I work in the same office. I go to the document DB and download a copy of document XYZ.xml and start making changes. At the same time, you also get a copy of that same document and start making your changes. When I'm done, I'll check in my changes (normal update function in sql). Then when you check your changes in, your changes will overwrite mine. Big problem.

However, if you can limit the document check out process to "exclusive" use (i.e., only one person can Check Out and Check In a document at a time), then XML document storage on SQL is possible without a ton of work. This can be done simply setting a flag in the document storage table, something like DocInUse=True. If DocInUse=True, then the document could not be downloaded again until it's checked back in and the DocINUse field = False. I'm sure you follow.

There are, by the way, applications out there that do this for you. There's Team Foundation Server and Source Safe from Microsoft, plus other programs that allow for this kind of storage and Check-out/Check-in processing ... but these programs are not cheap.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I've clearly not explained myself. I have no intention of having several people working on the same xml document, just the data.xml file which is effectively a config file for the application itself which stores data about who has the document, notes relating to it and various other bits of data about the xml documents themselves. This is the only file that currently needs to be shared simultaneously and this is due to the fact that i'm working outside of a DB.

Comment: I realise there are other applications out there that do similar things, but they also have a lot of functionality that we don't need, and don't have much of the other functionality that we do need. I was giving a brief overview of the app for clarity without wanting going into huge depths about it.
The program works fine and is exactly what we need, i just would like to have it all contained in a DB. That was all.